# Couldn't resolve host registered by GKE internal lb(ingress)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

In GKE clsuter, I can't call with hostname in internal http loadbalancer config.
This is generated ingress yaml file.

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: '{"k8s1-d21262da-default-hellorest-backend-service-80-698951b3":"HEALTHY","k8s1-d21262da-kube-system-default-http-backend-80-43d0837a":"HEALTHY"}'
    ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule: k8s2-fr-h23zc63d-default-hellorest-ingress-i-jxaunyik
    ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy: k8s2-tp-h23zc63d-default-hellorest-ingress-i-jxaunyik
    ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s2-um-h23zc63d-default-hellorest-ingress-i-jxaunyik
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce-internal
  creationTimestamp: "2021-04-08T09:29:50Z"
  finalizers:
  - networking.gke.io/ingress-finalizer-V2
  generation: 1
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubernetes.io/ingress.class: {}
      f:spec:
        f:rules: {}
    manager: GoogleCloudConsole
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-04-08T09:29:50Z"
  - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          f:ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: {}
          f:ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule: {}
          f:ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy: {}
          f:ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: {}
        f:finalizers:
          .: {}
          v:"networking.gke.io/ingress-finalizer-V2": {}
      f:status:
        f:loadBalancer:
          f:ingress: {}
    manager: glbc
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-04-08T09:30:44Z"
  name: hellorest-ingress-i
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "39841"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/hellorest-ingress-i
  uid: 728a4e1b-8435-4b1e-a378-82665e7a8a6c
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hellorest-backend-service
          servicePort: 80
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 10.178.100.7
```

In one of cluster node, service is successfully called with load balncer IP address. But call with hostname does not work.

```sh
# success with ip
$ curl http://10.224.13.150/hello
I am hellorest-backend-67fddc48f9-5hnmg(10.220.0.7)

# cannot resolve host
$ curl http://hello/hello
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'hello'
```

More about test environments.

- `GKE Cluster`: zonal / private cluster / 1.18.16-gke.302 / 2 nodes / control plane 172.16.0.0/28, global access disabled / http load balancing enabled
- `deployed service`: hellorest-backend-service / 3 pods / 80 to 8080 tcp forwarding / default namespace / NodePort
- `ingress service`: hellorest-ingress-i / internal http(s) lb / default namespace / 10.178.100.7 / no problem in health check

Comment: Hello @YoungrokKo. Do you happen to have a DNS private zone with a record: hello? Please take a look [here](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-private-dns-zones/), it should make it work. Also, it can be done from the cloud console. Please let me know if that is the case.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Thank you. It's perfectly working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, in order to make it work you need to have a DNS private zone with a record A: `hello`.
That can be done by using a cloud console. [Google Cloud Private DNS Zones](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-private-dns-zones/) explains that in more detail:

> Google Cloud DNS can now provide:
>
> 1. Create private DNS zones to provide DNS name resolution to your private network resources (VMs, load balancers, etc.).
> 2. Connect a private zone to a single network or multiple networks, giving you flexibility when designing your internal network
>    architectures.
> 3. Create split-horizon DNS architectures where identical or overlapping zones can coexist between public and private zones in
>    Cloud DNS, or across different GCP networks.
> 4. Utilize IAM-based, DNS-specific roles to delegate administrative or editor access to manage or view managed private zones.

All the necessary info and examples can be found in the linked article.